# fql to get location posts by me or my friends with me tagged

Tags: union, facebook-fql, facebook-rest-api

Here is what i'm looking for:

*select author_uid, tagged_uids, page_id  from location_post where author_uid = me() or ( author_uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and me() in tagged_uids)*

When i split the queries they return the expected results.

i.e, both

1. *select author_uid, tagged_uids, page_id  from location_post where author_uid = me()*
2. *select author_uid, tagged_uids, page_id  from location_post where author_uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and me() in tagged_uids*

work as expected. What I need is a union of the 2.
I'm tempted to say this is either a bug (or a limitation) in the API

Note:

1. The OR clause itself works if the hard code one of my friend's id and my id. i.e **author_uid=<my-id> or (author_uid=<frnd-id> and <my-id> in tagged_uids)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was me() in the query. I had the user's ID around and replace me() with the actual ID did the the job

```
SELECT id, author_uid, page_id, tagged_uids, timestamp, coords FROM location_post WHERE (&lt;id> IN tagged_uids or author_uid = &lt;id>)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do will not work. You could try and run a multi-query and get back the results at once and compare them on your end.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right what I was trying did not work. I have added an answer describing what worked!